# Is this on-topic for Literature SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

I posted [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/419783/is-alliteration-adjacent-words-and-or-close-together-words-starting-with-the-sam) question on ELU SE to much uproar (it is now on-hold), so I [asked](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11016/why-is-my-alliteration-question-off-topic-and-put-on-hold) why it was being closed, on ELU Meta and they seem to suggest I migrate it to Literature SE. Would my original question be on-topic for Literature SE, after I originally thought it would be more relevant for ELU? I am so confused!

Here is the question:

Is alliteration adjacent words and/or close together words starting with the same letter? If words between are permitted then how many?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post what the exact question is here so that we don't have to visit ELU to see what the question is? Thanks!

Comment: @Mithrandir Sure, I've edited it in. Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, what's wrong with asking the question and seeing what happens.

Comment: @Hamlet OK, thanks! It's just that there were quite a few people unhappy about it on ELU so I just thought I'd check first...

Comment: Do you have an image of the original question for those of us who have less than 10k reputation on ELU?

Comment: It’s been deleted by a mod on ELU now and I have posted [it](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/4710/is-alliteration-adjacent-words-and-or-close-together-words-starting-with-the-sam/4713#4713) on Literature main site now, as Hamlet suggested.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Honestly, just ask the question on the site and see if people downvote it/vote to close it. That's a lot easier than writing the question and a detailed meta question as well. Meta is primarily a tool for when there's controversy on the main site about how to deal with an issue. Since you haven't posted the question yet, we would just be speculating about how it would be received. Since not everyone reads meta, our speculation most likely wouldn't be that much use.

If you don't believe me, here's a community manager saying the exact same thing: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1571/8960

Comment: Advising posting it on the main site I can support. Advising posting it because people don't read meta is antithetical to the way site metas work. We _want_ people to ask here if they're unsure. In addition to being untrue - people _do_ read meta - it devalues/misrepresents meta discussion, making it seem like meta isn't a useful or valuable resource for the site.

Comment: `Meta is primarily a tool for when there's controversy on the main site about how to deal with an issue.` - I'm sorry, but I disagree with this. Meta is used for determining if something is on topic before it's asked, or for discussing guidelines, or for organizing an event or whatever, topic challenges, fun... Resolving controversies, while one function of Meta, is by no means its *only* use.

Comment: @Mithrandir if you don't believe me, here's Shog (the closest you can get to an authority on how Stack Exchange works) saying the exact same thing: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1600/8960